# Adding gradient with :after pseudo-class on Google Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, google-maps

## First of all:

The problem is that I want to add a gradient layer on top of Google Map with CSS, and so far I would be able to add it. However, the problem is it just blocking map from panning, and I can't pan my map by adding `:after`, how can I achieve that desired effect with CSS?

Here is my `:after`

```
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: radial-gradient(#ff72734d, #9198e570); // colors has less opacity baked on their hex values, by that i can see map it self...
```

## Secondly:

Is it possible to make a div on top of all elements that does not block user from selecting elements behind of that div (even better way instead of `:after` ), by that I would be able to add another div that has a gradient effect on it to be placed on top of the Google Map layer, is it possible?

By the way, I'm using `react` with `react-google-maps` , but if you guys know any solution for this problem , you know that it is so simple to add that by CSS, but I'm hinting `react-google-maps` here just because of may be some one know a better way with javascript to add the desired effect.

## Desired effect is something like below

Please notice those gradients around map that I pointed with red arrows

[image]

Comment: you could add pointer-events:none; so you can click through it .  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: thank you @G-Cyr that solved my problem....